# How to install extension into visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add an extension to Visual Studio 2012, but cannot get it to work.

I have tried going through tools->extensions and updates, find 'local history' but this just opens to the webpage, if I download it, nothing more happens, I restart Visual Studio and still nothing.

I then tried copying it to Extensions folder in %APPDATA%/roaming
but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a way,

If I double click the vsix file, and select visual studio version selector, it installs the extension.

surprised the other ways didnt work but i think this did, still waiting to see.